# access member of subtype case class when present in all used subtypes

Tags: scala, inheritance

I'm writing a ScalaTest reporter and currently I have two case class events 'TestSucceeded' and 'TestFailed', which extend 'Event' and I have a function:

```
def getInfo(event: Event) {
  println(event.suiteName)
}
```

the suiteName String is a member of both the 'TestSucceeded' and 'TestFailed' case classes, but not Event and I can't find a better way of implementing than

```
def getInfo(event: Event) {
  if(event.isInstanceOf[TestSucceeded])
    println(event.asInstanceOf[TestSucceeded].suiteName)
  else println(event.asInstanceOf[TestFailed].suiteName)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can think of three ways to do what you want without modifying the definition of either of the classes.

First, *type classes*:

```
    object EventTypeClasses {
      sealed trait Named[T] { def suiteName(t: T) String }
      implicit object Succeeded extends Named[TestSucceed] {
         def suiteName(t: TestSucceeded) = t.suitName
      }
      implicit object Failed extends Named[TestFailed] {
         def suiteName(t: TestFailed) = t.suitName
      }
    }
    ...
    import EventTypeClasses._
    def getInfo[T <: Event : Named](event: T): Unit = {
       implicitly[Named[T]].suitName(event)
    }
}
```

Another way is "pimp my library" trick:

```
    object EventWithName {
      sealed trait It { def suitName: String }
      implicit class Succeeded(e: TestSucceeded) extends It { def suitName = e.suitName }
      implicit class Failed(e: TestFailed) extends It { def suitName = e.suiteName } 
     }

     ... 


     def getInfo(event: EventWithName.It) = println(event.suiteName)

     ...
     import EventWithName._
     getInfo(new TestSucceeded(...))
```

Finally, `structural types`. This uses reflection and so is usually frowned upon, but if you are only going to use it for testing it is probably fine:

```
   type Named = { def suiteName: String }
   def getInfo(event: Named) = println(event.suiteName)
```

You can also just use match-case, if this is the only place you need it, so that it doesn't get repetitive:

```
    def getInfo(event: Event) = event match {
      case e: TestSucceeded => println(e.suiteName)
      case e: TestFailed => println(e.suiteName)
      case _ => ???
    }
```

You can combine this with the "pimp" thing above to make it look nicer (so that you don't have to deal with the weird `EventWithName.It`, and the users of `getInfo` don't need to import the implicits:

```
    object EventWithName {
      implicit class Pimped(val event: Event) extends AnyVal { 
        def suitName = event match { 
           case e: TestSucceeded => e.suiteName
           case e: TestFailed => e.suiteName
           case _ => ???
        }
      }
     }
     import EventWithName._ 
     def getInfo(e: Event) = {
       println(e.suiteName)
       doOtherThingsWithEvent(e)
     }

     ... 

     // No need to import implicits here
     getInfo(new TestSucceeded(...))
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider **algebraic data type** via `sealed abstract class` like so

```
sealed abstract class Event(val suiteName: String)
case class TestSucceeded(suite: String) extends Event(suite)
case class TestFailed(suite: String) extends Event(suite)

def getInfo(event: Event): Unit = println(event.suiteName)

getInfo(TestSucceeded("ASpec"))   // ASpec
getInfo(TestSucceeded("BSpec"))   // BSpec
```

Comment: Unfortunately the Event class and TestSucceeded and TestFailed case classes aren't my classes, sorry I should have made that clearer, they come from the ScalaTest library, and myreporter is just intercepting them

Answer (score 1):

So what you have is something like this:

```scala
sealed trait Event
case class TestSucceeded(suiteName: String) extends Event
case class TestFailed(suiteName: String) extends Event
case class TestWithNoSuiteName() extends Event
```

One way of making it cleaner would be to use pattern matching:

```scala
def getInfo(event: Event) = println(event match {
  case e: TestSucceeded => e.suiteName
  case e: TestFailed => e.suiteName
})

getInfo(TestSucceeded("foo")) // foo
getInfo(TestFailed("bar")) // bar
getInfo(TestWithNoSuiteName()) // scala.MatchError
```

Another way would be to define a type to prevent passing an `Event` with no `suiteName` at compile-time:

```scala
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
type SuiteName = { val suiteName: String }
def getInfo(event: Event with SuiteName) = {
  println(event.suiteName)
}

getInfo(TestSucceeded("foo")) // foo
getInfo(TestFailed("bar")) // bar
getInfo(TestWithNoSuiteName()) // doesn't compile
```

Comment: Thanks, since I had 3 values shared between TestSucceeded and TestFailed your idea of using type worked really well

Answer (score 1):

A reflective call using a structural type will do what you want. This is not recommended for production code but is probably OK in test code

```
def getInfo(event: { def suiteName: String }) =
  event.suiteName
```